# PHP: dompdf not loading custom font

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm facing a problem with dompdf library. I need to use Myriad Pro as font for the pdf I'm creating at runtime.
When the pdf is created, the font dompdf uses is Helvetica.

I've put 2 .ttf files under a folder I created under the root folder and named it 'fonts'. I try to load the font at runtime using the CSS property font-face and then using it in the html I'm producing.

Here's a sample of the html/css I'm writing in the PHP file:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: Myriad-Pro-Regular;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        src: url("/fonts/Myriad-Pro-Regular.ttf")format ("truetype");
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: Myriad-Pro-Bold;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        src: url("/fonts/Myriad-Pro-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
    }
    html {
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        margin-left: 70px;
        margin-right: 60px;
        font-family: Myriad-Pro-Regular,sans-serif;
    }';
```

Any ideas why I'm doing this wrong?